# How to iterate (outside a class) a private member which is a vector<unique_ptr<T>>

Tags: c++, c++11

```
class Organization {
 private:
  vector<unique_ptr<Employee>> employees_;
  vector<unique_ptr<Item>> items_;
}org;
```

I need to have a facility outside the class to iterate over the employees and items and call their members, like the following...

```
for(auto const& e : getEmployees()) { e.get()->getName(); }
```

But I cannot make `getEmployees()` function to return `employees_`, as vector of unique_ptrs is not copyable

So currently I'm having a for_each_employee function

```
template<class callable>
void Organization::for_each_employee(callable f) {
     for(auto const& e : employees_) {
        f(e.get());
   }
}

// And I use it like,
org.for_each_employee([](Employee* e){ e->getName(); });
```

But I do not like this idea as I'll have to write for_each_employee and for_each_item. I have similar other classes of the similar structure. So I will end up writing lot of for_each_XX type functions. This is not what I want.

Can I have generic for_each function that are friends of these classes (like Organization that contain vector of unique_ptrs)?

How to iterate (outside a class) a private member which is a `vector<unique_ptr<T>>`

Comment: Why not return-by-reference instead?

Comment: or return iterators to the vectors

Comment: You can return reference of employee_ in getEmployees() to iterate

Comment: Yes I agree, half way through typing this question I tried the same and got an error as I still had the getItems functions returning a copy. But I was stupid and overlooked the error. I got it working now, I have getEmployees and getItems returning by references. Thanks for your time people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest and quite readable approach is to provide an access method that returns a possibly `const`-qualified reference to the data member. This way, you don't try to copy non-copyable members.

```
const vector<unique_ptr<Item>>& getItems()
{
    return items_;
}
```

which can be used like this

```
for (const auto& item : organizationInstance.getItems())
    item->doStuff();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can return reference of employee_ in getEmployees() to iterate

```
const vector<unique_ptr<Employee>>& getEmployees()
{
    return employee_;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is iterators. `std::vector::begin()` and `std::vector::end()` return iterators to the first and to the one-past-the-end elements of the vector. Then you can do stuff like.

```
for (auto iter = organization.get_employees_begin(); iter != organization.get_employees.end(); ++iter) {
    do_something(*iter);
}
```

Where

```
class Organization {
    auto get_employees_begin() { return employees_.begin(); }
    auto get_employees_begin() const { return employees_.begin(); }

    auto get_employees_end() { return employees_.end(); }
    auto get_employees_end() const { return employees_.end(); }
}
```

The `const` versions return `const` iterators, which are similar to pointers-to-`const` in that they don't allow modification of the vector. The added benefit of this method over returning a reference to the vector is that it completely decouples the implementation from the interface. If you don't care about that for whatever reason, you can use this instead.

```
class Organization {
    auto& get_employees() { return employees_; }
    const auto& get_employees() const { return employees_; }
}
```

This will allow you to use all vector utilities but it will also make all your code that relies on them break if the internal container changes from a vector to something else.

In any case, you might not want to provide the non-`const` functions if the vector should not be modified directly.

Comment: I like the point about decoupling. In that case, I can also return a pair of iterators. But the usage will become confusing :) 

   for(auto iter = organization.getEmployees().first(); iter != organization.getEmployees().second(); ++iter) { do_something(*iter); }

or I shuold tie it to variables

Comment: Personally I wouldn't use the paired version because I think `get_employees_begin` is much clearer to anyone who has used iterators.

Comment: you dont have "completely" decoupled the the implementation from the interface. The iterator returned is still a `vector<unique_ptr<Employee>>::iterator` and it will be a different type when vector is exchanged with a different container. Using `auto` in the client code helps to be independent of the underlying container, but `auto` helps just the same when you return the vector directly

Comment: @user463035818 There are more issues to consider besides the type of the returned value. For example you can iterate over a vector with `operator[]` but that code will break when you change the container type to a non-contiguous one. Returning an iterator conveys the interface you intend to offer and makes it harder for the user to use your interface in non-portable ways..

Comment: yes, sure. I just stumbled upon your wording, because it is possible to **complelety** decouple the interface from the implementation, but strictly speaking you are not doing it

Comment: @user463035818 How would you do that?

Comment: not sure, depends on the case, maybe return an `EmployeeIterator` that hides the type of the container from the user. On the other hand it isnt always possible or necessary to completely decouple the interface from the implementation ;)

Answer (score 1):

To allow only iterating, not giving any more vector-specific operations You can use `boost::range`

```
auto getItems() {
    return boost::make_iterator_range(employees_.begin(), employees_.end());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple span class.  It is similar to `gsl::span`.  It represents a view into a contiguous buffer of `T` elements (like in an array):

```
template<class T>
struct span {
  T* begin() const { return b; }
  T* end() const { return e; }
  T* data() const { return begin(); }
  std::size_t size() const { return end()-begin(); }
  bool empty() const { return size()==0; }

  span( T* s, T* f ):b(s),e(f) {}
  span( T* s, std::size_t length ):span(s, s+length){}

  span() = default;

  template<class A>
  span( std::vector<T, A>& v ):
    span(v.data(), v.length() )
  {}
  template<class A>
  span( std::vector<std::remove_const_t<T>, A> const& v ):
    span(v.data(), v.length() )
  {}
  template<std::size_t N>
  span( T(& arr)[N] ):
    span(arr, N)
  {}
  template<std::size_t N>
  span( std::array<T, N>& arr ):
    span(arr.data(), N)
  {}
  template<std::size_t N>
  span( std::array<std::remove_const_t<T>, N> const& arr ):
    span(arr.data(), N)
  {}

private:
  T* b = 0;
  T* e = 0;
};
```

simply have your `getEmployees` return a `span<std::unique_ptr<Employee> const>`.

This exposes everything the caller needs to iterate over it efficiently, and no more.

The simpler alternative is to return a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Employee>> const&`, but that leaks implementation details that are utterly irrelevant to the consumer of `getEmployee`.