# Call a function with a part of a larger array

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm refactoring some code and have decided that I would like to merge a two-dimensional array into a one-dimensional, larger array. The problem is now that I have some functions which take those smaller arrays as parameter and I would prefer to keep their signatures. Is it possible to call a function with only a part of a larger array?

f1 is what I currently have and f2 is what it should look like after refactoring:

```
#include <array>

void func(std::array<int const, 5> const& arr, int i);

void f1() {
    static std::array<std::array<int const, 5>, 2> const arr{{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 0}}};
    func(arr[0], 0);
    func(arr[1], 1);
}

void f2() {
    static std::array<int const, 10> const arr{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0};
    //TODO: call func with first and last 5 elements. 
}
```

Comment: Well, no, it's not possible to pass part of an `std::array<int const, 10>` to a function expecting a `std::array<int const, 5>` without creating a copy.     Why not change `func()` so it accepts a pair of iterators representing begin and end (or, if you know you can safely assume 5 elements, accepts a single iterator corresponding to the first element).    That makes it completely independent of how the caller organises its data.

Comment: @Peter I wanted to keep the signature clear in its intent that it only works with a certain number of elements. But I like the idea with only accepting the begin iterator and keep the number of elements hardcoded in the function. Didn't think of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your function to to take a range of elements as Peter commented, this becomes trivial. You would pass `arr.begin()` and `arr.begin() + 5` for the first array and `arr.begin() + 5`, `arr.end()` for the second.

```c++
void func(int* b, int* e, int i);
```

You can also take a `span` just to make things cleaner. Here [`gsl::span`](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl/span) is used but you can [write your own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52315482/701092) if you want:

```c++
#include <gsl/span>

void func(gsl::span<int> s, int i);

static std::array<int const, 10> const arr{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0};
func( {arr.begin(), arr.begin() + 5}, 0 );
func( {arr.begin() + 5, arr.end()}, 1 );
```

Comment: But size of 5 is no longer checked from signature. (depends of `func` to know if it is important or not).

Comment: @Jarod42 You can do `static_assert( s.size() == 5 )`

Comment: **Parameters** are not `constexpr`, so `assert`, but not `static_assert`.

Comment: @Jarod42 `size()` is `constexpr`

Comment: @Jarod42 But `s` doesn't need to be. What about [this example](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6faf83b0aa398ef9)?

Comment: but `s.size()` depends of `s` for `span` contrary to `std::array`. (Cannot find available `<span>` on online compiler for corresponding example, so [Demo with int](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d20830aea24bf0f)).

Comment: @Jarod42 Not sure I understand. You mean `static_assert(s.size() == 5`) won't compile?

Comment: exactly, we would need something like a "`fixed_size_view<int, 5>`" to compile.